# Android : Using layoutinflater for custom layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing a videoconference APP where I have a framelayout which will have surfaceview to render video and Button to end that participant call.

since the participants can be added dynamically I have to inflate this layout when ever request comes to create a new user.

this inflated layout will be added into tablelayout so that I can accommodate many layouts / users in which ever order I want.

I am inflating the FrameLayout like :

```
participantHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_paritcipant_layout, null);
```

and I am getting the surface view button inside this layout using :

```
//get the Dropuser button
participantHolder.mParticipantDropButton = (ImageButton)mFrameLayt.findViewById(R.id.ParticipantDropButton);
//get the surfaceview
participantHolder.mParticipantSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)mFrameLayt.findViewById(R.id.ParticipantSurfaceView);
```

and adding the layout into table row by setting the layout params.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams PreviewLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
PreviewLayoutParams.weight = 1;
CurrentParticpant.mParticipantUIHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(PreviewLayoutParams);
CurrentParticpant.mParticipantUIHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout.invalidate();
mTableRowOne.addView(CurrentParticpant.mParticipantUIHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout);
mTableRowOne.invalidate();
mTableLayoutReference.invalidate();
```

But I am not able to see the View/Layout at all please let me if am doing some thing wrong

Comment: Shouldn't your `mParticipantDropButton` and `mParticipantSurfaceView` be inside `mParticipantFrameLayout`?

Comment: mFrameLayt here is nothing but I am referencing it as mFrameLayt = participantHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout; both are same

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is here:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams PreviewLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

First argument means width and you set it to 0. Please try the following:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams PreviewLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
```

Using such constructor you don't need to add `PreviewLayoutParams.weight = 1;`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#TableRow.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20float%29

Comment: I think the problem is not that because I am giving the weight=1 which means the entire layout width space.

Comment: Hmm NO I am giving width as 0 because my table Row Orientation is Horizontal, so when I add one more Layout into it, then it should equally align 2 layouts, the problem is still present. :(

Comment: what if you'll remove `CurrentParticpant.mParticipantUIHolder.mParticipantFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(PreviewLayoutParams);`? also calls of `invalidate()` after `addView()` can be removed I think